# Auto-resizing texture at the beginning of the animation

Tags: ios, swift, sprite, xscale

I have one question. For animation of my object i using this method in Player class:

```
func animationPlayerMovement(action: Bool) {
        for i in 1...3 {
            let name = "player \(i)"
            playerTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
        }
        if(action == true){
        playerMovement = SKAction.animate(with: playerTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: true, restore: true)

  self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(playerMovement))
        }else{
            self.removeAllActions()
        }
    }
```

And call this method in function touchesBegan(), when i using virtual joystik.
Direction of my sprite take from condition in function touchesMoved():

```
if(velocityX < 0){
                    player.xScale = -1
                }else{
                    player.xScale = 1
                }
```

But i have a problem, size of my sprite is changed when i started moving, he becomes bigger by width and heigth.
If i change resize in SKAction.animate to false, height is normal, but width change to small and normal for all time of animation. Object "player" was created with this parameters:

```
    player.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 60)
    player.xScale = 1
    player.yScale = 1
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?